# Problems using ROME feedreader

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rome

Im trying to make a newsreader on android 4.1 using the [ROME Feed Reader](https://code.google.com/p/android-rome-feed-reader/). However, I keep getting errors when my app is trying to call a newsfeed. I've been busy implementing Asynctask, because 4.1 doesn't let me retrieve rss-feeds on the main thread.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.cloud.backend.android/com.google.cloud.backend.android.FeedActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.cloud.backend.android.FeedListAdapter.getCount(FeedListAdapter.java:32)
        at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:466)
        at com.google.cloud.backend.android.FeedActivity.createList(FeedActivity.java:34)
        at com.google.cloud.backend.android.FeedActivity.onCreate(FeedActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
```

Here's my code (partially):

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private SyndFeed feed;
    private Activity context;

    public FeedListAdapter( Activity context )
    {
        this.context = context;
        String feedUrl = context.getIntent().getExtras().getString("Feed");
        new FeedRetrieval().execute(feedUrl);
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return feed.getEntries().size();
    }

    ... (shortened)

    private class FeedRetrieval extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            RssAtomFeedRetriever feedRetriever = new RssAtomFeedRetriever();
            feed = feedRetriever.getMostRecentNews(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Edit**:
I've changed getCount() to:

```
if (feed != null) {
    return feed.getEntries().size();
}
return 0;
```

But now i get:

```
07-28 01:14:34.182: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29175): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-28 01:14:34.242: ERROR/android.os.Debug(433): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Logcat doesn't show what causes AsyncTask to fail. This makes even less sense to me :(

Answer (score 0):

Your `feed` variable is `null` until the `AsyncTask` finishes executing. If you call `getCount` before it is finished, it will try to access `feed`, which is `null` at that time.

Either return a default value or offer a way to check if the data is actually present.

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion, but now i'm getting a completely different error (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I've got it. The example is hosted on my GitHub: https://github.com/praetore/AndroidROMEFeedReader